# When is the Infinite product of continuous functions a continuous function? Assume that the product is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, infinite-product

Is there any theorem about the continuity of an infinite product of continuous **real valued** functions on compact Housdorff spaces, if the product is convergent?
I mean, for each natural number $n$, let $X_n$ be a compact Housdorff space and $f_n: X_n\to R$ be a continuous function ($R$ denotes the set of real numbers). Assume that the product $∏_{n=1}^∞ f_n$ converges to a function $f$. Then what can we say about the continuity of $f$? By the convergence of the product $∏_{n=1}^∞ f_n$ I mean the following:[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want the space where the functions are defined to be dependent on $n$? Apart from that: by applying the (continuous and one-one) function $\log$ you can reduce this to the case of infinite series.

Comment: @Thomas Well I was just considering the countable collection, So here is my question: Do we've convergence for arbitrary indexing set?

Comment: Can you define a product (of elements of a field) with an uncountable number of factors? Before you consider that kind of construction of functions, you should provide the concept for more elementary objects.

Comment: @Thomas that's why I picked the countable set and the definition of convergence of countable products is  already attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the $f_n$ are continuous and the convergence is uniform then the limit $f(x)$ is continuous. If that's not the case nothing much because you can easily set a counter example by looking at the 
set $ C$, where {$C \in R : f(x) \neq 0$}and taking $\log|f|$.

Proof : $\epsilon ,\delta \ge 0$

$g_n∏_{m=1}^n f_n$, clearly each $g_n$ is continuous

$\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n = f(x)$

Uniform convergence implies that for some large $N$, such that for all $n \ge N$, we have $|f(x)-g_n(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $x$

By continuity of $g_n$, we have  $|g_n(x+dx)-g_n(x)|  \le \delta$

$|f(x+dx)-f(x)| \le |f(x+dx)-g_n(x)| +|g_n(x)-f(x)|  \le  |f(x+dx)-g_n(x+dx)|+|g_n(x+dx)-g_n(x)| +|g_n(x)-f(x)|  \le 2\epsilon+\delta $

Since $\epsilon , \delta$ are arbitrary it implies $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Yeah I need this result "If the convergence is uniform then the limit f(x) is continuous", can you please share link? I want to see the research paper. Also, does all the functions need to be bounded ?

Comment: @Prince Khan U asking whether uniform convergence of sequence of continuous functions has a limit function that is continuous ?

Comment: I wanted the proof. Thanks!